# file comparing function in python ignoring a particular string

Tags: python-2.7

I am newbie in python, I have to compare two files but also at the same time how can I ignore a particular string content in that compare.
For Example:

A.txt content:

```
             /usr/bin: line 5:  user_input: command not found
             /usr/bin: line 19: user_input: command not found
```

B.txt content:

```
            /usr/bin: line 51: user_input: command not found
            /usr/bin: line 23: user_input: command not found
```

While comparing these two files I want to just ignore the line numbers.

How can I do it using a single function similar to `filecmp.dircmp(dir1,dir2,ignore)` for directories.
Is there any function in python we can do it for files also.

Comment: For example, you can read content line by line, replace lines numbers with regexp - see `re.sub()` (if format of ignoring part may be complex) or with simple `str.translate()` - to delete integers

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for some function we can call directly something like filecmp.cmp(A.txt, B.txt) and the string needs to be ignore passed as argument.

Comment: no such... But you can look this - https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html , it generates diff objects for files but I'm not sure that this is the right way. Right way will be to write such function